# Expandir altura de un textarea de acuerdo al contenido que recibe al cargar la pagina

Tags: css, html5, typescript, angular8

Tengo un textarea que recibe datos de una funcion.  Pero al mostrarse el textarea solo se muestra una porcion del contenido y lo que busco es que el textarea se expanda en altura para poder mostrar todo el contenido en primera vista.

este es el textarea :

```html
<textarea matInput class='scroll lblNombre  cajas-texto'
                                (keyup)="autoGrowTextZone($event)" [(ngModel)]="ModeloPblEdit.pblDes" name="cmtTtl"
                                maxlength="1700" spellcheck="false"
                                style="resize: none; width: 100% !important; font-family: Garamond; font-size: 17px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Has intentado esto https://material.angular.io/cdk/text-field/overview

Comment: Me hiciste recordar que existia "cdkTextareaAutosize" y con eso se soluciono el problema.  Gracias!

Comment: @HernanRiosValencia pon eso como respuesta (con una breve descripción de qué es lo que hace `cdkTextareaAutosize`, dónde iría en el código, y un enlace a la documentación si es posible) y márcala como aceptada.